# PHP GD Stronger Antialias

Tags: php, gd, antialiasing

I'm using GD to plot some simple charts from array point data.. Trying to optimize the appearance - even using `imageantialias` , there is still a significantly notice-able jag in the line between the points. What's a better way to PHP GD antialias a line between two points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the simplest solution is to unzip JPGraph (http://jpgraph.net), and use the chart classes -- the lines come out amazingly anti-aliased, and dare I say, pretty!

(ImageMagick is a pain to set up on CentOS servers - the above methods of blowing up and reducing does not seem to improve antialiasing..)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of limitations with GD and just as many awkward workarounds. I'd suggest using [ImageMagick](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) instead to get better drawing tools without the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

How about applying [`imagefilter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php)'s `IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR`, `IMG_FILTER_SELECTIVE_BLUR`, or `IMG_FILTER_SMOOTH` just on the line?

Comment: How do you apply it just on the line? Applying it to the image resource just makes it look blurred, but the jags are still evident...

Comment: Create the line on a separate transparent image that can be superimposed on the background image

Comment: the original image has just the single line - applying the blur/smooth filters simply blurs the line, but the jags are still in place http://ina-zntvj.posterous.com/php-gd-jaggedness

Comment: have u tried doubling the size of the image, applying a blur/antialias on the line, then reducing it to normal size?

Answer (score 0):

It's possibly the case that your line *is* antialiased correctly, but that you also need to gamma correct the image.  I don't know if GD makes that easy for you, but I've seen the effect in my own line rendering code, and the appropriate gamma value is dependent on the monitor you're using.

Comment: Even with a black and white image, you might still need to gamma correct it.  Basically, the code will put value 127 into your pixel array, hoping for a medium shade of grey, but your monitor will render that closer to white or black, and it will throw off the antialiasing effect.

Comment: I'm not a PHP guy, but it looks like "bool imagegammacorrect ( resource $image , float $inputgamma , float $outputgamma )" might help.

Comment: No perceptive difference applying `imagegammacorrect` with several different input/ouput (1.0,2.5,permutations of)... Moreover, using that it'd be device-dependent -- if I viewed it on a Mac vs a PC, I'd need a different in/out gamma?

Comment: Sorry it didn't help.  Take care.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, seems I downvoted on you(or I changed that? seems I have  Critic badge now)

I used some hack, and it looks not so bad

http://i42.tinypic.com/72tzes.jpg

http://i42.tinypic.com/290yidi.png

i just draw few lines with less color behind main line

```
$arColor = imagecolorsforindex($im, $color);
$AAcolor = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, $arColor['red'], $arColor['green'], $arColor['blue'], 112);

imageline($im,round($prevX+1),round($prevY),round($x),round($y+1),$AAcolor);
imageline($im,round($prevX),round($prevY-1),round($x+1),round($y),$AAcolor);
imageline($im,round($prevX-1),round($prevY),round($x),round($y-1),$AAcolor);
imageline($im,round($prevX),round($prevY+1),round($x-1),round($y),$AAcolor);
imageline($im,round($prevX),round($prevY),round($x),round($y),$color);
```